# JOptionPane em primeiro plano

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

Tenho uma app que usa um `JOptionPane` para mostrar uma mensagem de erro, porém eu gostaria que o `JOptionPane` sempre aparecesse em primeiro plano.

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Usuário ou senha incorreto!", "Erro", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
```

Vi algo com trocar o `null` pelo `this` no primeiro parâmetro do `Dialog`, porém não funcionou.

Answer (score 1):

Olá, pelo que vi a sintaxe está errado.

Teste o código abaixo:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, //frame de referêcia
    "Usuário ou senha incorreto!",  //mensagem para o usuario
    "Inane error",                  //icone de erro pode deixar em branco ou null se não quiser usá-lo
    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);     //tipo de mensagem
```

Clique [aqui](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) para ir até a documentação do `showMessageDialog()`.

Answer (score 1):

Olá corrigindo uma pequena informação do colega:

```
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, //Qualquer Componente nao so Frame
    "Usuário ou senha incorreto!",  //mensagem para o usuario
    "Inane error",                  //icone de erro pode deixar em branco ou null se não quiser usá-lo
    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);     //tipo de mensagem
```

Um pequeno exemplo de código ,no qual, sem fechar o `JOptionPane` é impossível clicar os outros componentes no Frame.

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("teste");
    JPanel painel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 2));
    JButton button1 = new JButton("01");
    JButton button2 = new JButton("02");
    JButton button3 = new JButton("03");
    JButton button4 = new JButton("04");
    button1.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(button1, e.getActionCommand(), 
    "Titulo: Mensagem Informação ",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    });
    button2.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(button2, e.getActionCommand(), 
    "Titulo: Mensagem Questão ",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
    });
    button3.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(button3, e.getActionCommand(), 
    "Titulo: Mensagem Atenção ",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
    });
    button4.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(button4, e.getActionCommand(), 
    "Titulo: Mensagem Erro ",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }); 

    painel.add(button1);
    painel.add(button2);
    painel.add(button3);
    painel.add(button4);
    frame.add(painel);
    frame.setSize(400, 400);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

Agora, talvez você esteja atrás de um `JDialog` o mesmo tem uma opção chamada `AlwaysOnTop` que, quando true, mantém o mesmo sempre a frente de qualquer janela independe da qual selecione. Também pode ser usado para Substituir um JFrame.

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("teste");
    JPanel painel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 1));
    JButton button1 = new JButton("01");
    JButton button2 = new JButton("02");
     button1.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
       JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
       dialog.setSize(200, 200);
       dialog.add(new JLabel("JDialog Teste"));
       dialog.setAlwaysOnTop(true);//Fica sobre todas as janelas
       dialog.setModal(true);//Impede que seja as janelas em segundo plano sejam acessadas
       dialog.setVisible(true);
     });
     button2.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(button2, e.getActionCommand(), 
    "Titulo: Mensagem Erro ",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
     });

    painel.add(button1);
    painel.add(button2);
    frame.add(painel);
    frame.setSize(400, 400);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

Comment: Muito bom. Só faltou colocar corretamente os imports das classes usadas no exemplo e despachar pra EDT.

Comment: Achei que nao precisava, sorry rs.